# Linux and WinPE

Tags: linux

In the last few weeks I was trying to automate software testing process in my company. I found WinPE as the best method for me. At first I was automating some tests based on python which wasn't a problem and I got it to work. I load a custom WinPE and a test starts running in a separate command line window, if it fails or finish it sends an email notification

My problem is with linux test I have (I was never working with Linux) Currently this test uses Grub4dos to load a BZimage and a Linux test starts in a Linux environment. My goal is to use the same method as with python, so is it even possible to run Linux inside WinPE and how can I do that? is Grub the solution for me? I couldn't get it to work in WinPE.

Comment: AFAIK you cannot do that as WinPE is windows only. You should look at `tox` for testing python.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are you using WinPE for a clean pre-installed environment. You can do that for Linux (and Windows) by using virtualmachines and snapshots e.g under VirtualBox (either with Windows or Linux as host OS).

For Python testing, it is normally "clean" enough to use `virtualenv`. This is much simpler and much faster than booting a pre-installed environment. `tox` allows you to automate testing python by using `virtualenv` for multiple targets (e.g. CPython 2.7, 3.3, 3.4, PyPy, Stackless).